# Circle covering algorithm with varying radii

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

For a game, I'm drawing dense clusters of several thousand randomly-distributed circles with varying radii, defined by a sequence of (x,y,r) triples. Here's an example image consisting of 14,000 circles:

[image: example image consisting of 14,000 circles]

I have some dynamic effects in mind, such as merging clusters, but for this to be possible I'll need to redraw all the circles every frame.

Many (maybe 80-90%) of the circles that are drawn are covered over by subsequent draws. Therefore I suspect that with preprocessing I can significantly speed up my draw loop by eliminating covered circles. Is there an algorithm that can identify them with reasonable efficiency?

I can tolerate a fairly large number of false negatives (ie draw some circles that are actually covered), as long as it's not so many that drawing efficiency suffers. I can also tolerate false positives as long as they're almost positive (eg remove some circles that are only 99% covered). I'm also amenable to changes in the way the circles are distributed, as long as it still looks okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example image you provided, it seems your circles have a near-constant radius. If their radius cannot be lower than a significant number of pixels, you could take advantage of the simple geometry of circles to try an image-space approach.

Imagine you divide your rendering surface in a grid of squares so that the smallest rendered circle can fit into the grid like this:

[image: grid 1][image: grid 2]

the circle radius is sqrt(10) grid units and covers at least 21 squares, so if you mark the squares entirely overlapped by any circle as already painted, you  will have eliminated approximately 21/10pi fraction of the circle surface, that is about 2/3.

You can get some ideas of optimal circle coverage by squares [here](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/)

The culling process would look a bit like a reverse-painter algorithm:

```
For each circle from closest to farthest
   if all squares overlapped (even partially) by the circle are painted
       eliminate the circle
   else
       paint the squares totally overlapped by the circle
```

You could also 'cheat' by painting grid squares not entirely covered by a given circle (or eliminating circles that overflow slightly from the already painted surface), increasing the number of eliminated circles at the cost of some false positives.

You can then render the remaining circles with a Z-buffer algorithm (i.e. let the GPU do the rest of the work).

**CPU-based approach**

This assumes you implement the grid as a memory bitmap, with no help from the GPU.

To determine the squares to be painted, you can use precomputed patterns based on the distance of the circle center relative to the grid (the red crosses in the example images) and the actual circle radius.

If the relative variations of diameter are small enough, you can define a two dimensional table of patterns indexed by circle radius and distance of the center from the nearest grid point.

Once you've retrieved the proper pattern, you can apply it to the appropriate location by using simple symmetries.

The same principle can be used for checking if a circle fits into an already painted surface.

**GPU-based approach**

It's been a long time since I worked with computer graphics, but if the current state of the art allows, you could let the GPU do the drawing for you.

Painting the grid would be achieved by rendering each circle scaled to fit the grid

Checking elimination would require to read the value of all pixels containing the circle (scaled to grid dimensions).

**Efficiency**

There should be some sweet spot for the grid dimension. A denser grid will cover a higher percentage of the circles surface and thus eliminate more circles (less false negatives), but the computation cost will grow in o(1/grid_step²).

Of course, if the rendered circles can shrink to about 1 pixel diameter, you could as well dump the whole algorithm and let the GPU do the work. But the efficiency compared with the GPU pixel-based approach grows as the square of the grid step.

Using the grid in my example, you could probably expect about 1/3 false negatives for a completely random set of circles.

For your picture, which seems to define volumes, 2/3 of the foreground circles and (nearly) all of the backward ones should be eliminated. Culling more than 80% of the circles might be worth the effort.

All this being said, it is not easy to beat a GPU in a brute-force computation contest, so I have only the vaguest idea of the actual performance gain you could expect. Could be fun to try, though.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of culling is essentially what hidden surface algorithms (HSAs) do - especially the variety called "object space".  In your case the sorted order of the circles gives them an effective constant depth coordinate. The fact that it's constant simplifies the problem.

A classical reference on HSA's is [here](http://design.osu.edu/carlson/history/PDFs/ten-hidden-surface.pdf). I'd give it a read for ideas.

An idea inspired by this thinking is to consider each circle with a "sweep line" algorithm, say a horizontal line moving from top to bottom.  The sweep line contains the set of circles that it's touching.  Initialize by sorting the input list of the circles by top coordinate.

The sweep advances in "events", which are the top and bottom coordinates of each circle. When a top is reached, add the circle to the sweep. When its bottom occurs, remove it (unless it's already gone as described below). As a new circle enters the sweep, consider it against the circles already there.  You can keep events in a max (y-coordinate) heap, adding them lazily as needed: the next input circle's top coordinate plus all the scan line circles' bottom coordinates.

A new circle entering the sweep can do any or all of 3 things.

1. Obscure circles in the sweep with greater depth. (Since we are identifying circles *not* to draw, the conservative side of this decision is to use the biggest included axis-aligned box (BIALB) of the new circle to record the obscured area for each existing deeper circle.)
2. Be obscured by other circles with lesser depth. (Here the conservative way is to use the BIALB of each other relevant circle to record the obscured area of the new circle.)
3. Have areas that are not obscured.

The obscured area of each circle must be maintained (it will generally grow as more circles are processed) until the scan line reaches its bottom.  If at any time the obscured area covers the entire circle, it can be deleted and never drawn.

The more detailed the recording of the obscured area is, the better the algorithm will work.  A union of rectangular regions is one possibility (see Android's Region code for example).  A single rectangle is another, though this is likely to cause many false positives.

Similarly a fast data structure for finding the possibly obscuring and obscured circles in the scan line is also needed. An interval tree containing the BIALBs is likely to be good.

Note that in practice algorithms like this only produce a win if the number of primitives is huge because fast graphics hardware is so ... fast.

Comment: I don't think the idea of maintaining each circle's amount of obscured area will work, because doing this accurately (or even conservatively) means you will need to avoid counting areas that a new circle obscures *which have already been obscured*, and that is tricky.  A better solution is, for each circle, to maintain a set of SIAABs (Smallest Including Axis-Aligned Box) that completely cover the as-yet-unobscured parts of the circle, and subtract out the BIALBs of covering circles as they arise.  If the set of SIAABs for a circle becomes empty, then it's invisible and can be deleted.

Comment: This sounds promising, but I don't understand the details. As I understand it, for each pair of consecutive events (horizontal lines), for each circle within the sweep at that time, I need to find the largest box completely covered by the circle. If nothing else, that seems like an awful lot of sqrt operations, no?

Also, what's Android's Region? Is it in the paper you linked to? (Sorry, I've only just started it.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple algorithm off the top of my head:

1. Insert the `N` circles into a quadtree (bottom circle first)
2. For each pixel, use the the quadtree to determine the top-most circle (if it exists)
3. Fill in the pixel with the color of the circle

By adding a circle, I mean add the center of the circle to the quadtree. This creates 4 children to a leaf node. Store the circle in that leaf node (which is now no longer a leaf). Thus each non-leaf node corresponds to a circle.

To determine the top-most circle, traverse the quadtree, testing each node along the way if the pixel intersects the circle at that node. The top-most circle is the one deepest down the tree that intersects the pixel.

This should take `O(M log N)` time (if the circles are distributed nicely) where `M` is the number of pixels and `N` is the number of circles. Worse case scenario is still `O(MN)` if the tree is degenerate.

Pseudocode:

```
quadtree T
for each circle c
    add(T,c)
for each pixel p
    draw color of top_circle(T,p)

def add(quadtree T, circle c)
    if leaf(T)
        append four children to T, split along center(c)
        T.circle = c
    else
        quadtree U = child of T containing center(c)
        add(U,c)

def top_circle(quadtree T, pixel p)
    if not leaf(T)
        if intersects(T.circle, p)
            c = T.circle
        quadtree U = child of T containing p
        c = top_circle(U,p) if not null
    return c
```

Comment: Cool, I like this. Just to be clear, the first loop is `O(Nd)`, where `d` is the depth of the quadtree, and you're assuming that the `O(M log N)` loop dominates this one, right? I just wonder if this might be faster: Initialize to false an array of booleans for each pixel. For each circle, starting at the top, set the boolean for each pixel it covers, and keep the circle only if it sets a previously unset boolean.

Comment: That's what I call a nice algorithm. The only trouble is, you will have the CPU do all the work and each circle will have a constant color (unless the CPU also does some lighting computation). Also, the actual efficiency of the tree will depend of the circles repartition. According to the image given as an example, I would expect about half the circles representing back facing surfaces, so you could expect something like an O(2M log N/2) computation time.

Answer (score 1):

If a circle is completely inside another circle, then it must follow that the distance between their centres plus the radius of the smaller circle is at most the radius of the larger circle (Draw it out for yourself to see!). Therefore, you can check:

```
float distanceBetweenCentres = sqrt((topCircle.centre.x - bottomCircle.centre.x) * (topCircle.centre.x - bottomCircle.centre.x) + (topCircle.centre.y - bottomCircle.centre.y) * (topCircle.centre.y - bottomCircle.centre.y));

if((bottomCircle.radius + distanceBetweenCentres) <= topCircle.radius){
  // The bottom circle is covered by the top circle.
}
```

To improve the speed of the computation, you can first check if the top circle has a larger radius that the bottom circle, as if it doesn't, it can't possibly cover the bottom circle. Hope that helps!

Comment: Well at some level, but if you have 10,000 circles, this must check about 1/2 * 10,000 * 10,000 pairs.  That's what makes this an interesting problem. Not to mention that one circle can be obscured by the union of several others, so pairwise comparisons are not that helpful

Comment: I was thinking to check this every time a new circle is added, to at least get pairwise circles removed.

Comment: My first thought was that while this is a very straightforward test, it will only match a tiny fraction of circles. However, I tested it on my example image, and I was surprised to see that it eliminates 51% of the green circles and 20% of the purple ones. So this may be worthwhile after all, at least as a first pass.

Comment: Awesome! It's definitely a fast check when adding in new circle's. There's plenty of more robust solutions as well, which would benefit from this one reducing the total count.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention a Z component, so I assume they are in Z order in your list and drawn back-to-front (i.e., painter algorithm).

As the previous posters said, this is an occlusion culling exercise.

In addition to the object space algorithms mentioned, I'd also investigate screen-space algorithms such as Hierarchical Z-Buffer. You don't even need z values, just bitflags indicating if something is there or not.

See: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131801/occlusion_culling_algorithms.php?print=1